# How can I add breakpoint into menu depend on screen size with twitter bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a reddit like top menu. the thing is there are too many items. How I can add a hamburger menu if screen size is x size but I don't want to take all the items into hamburger menu. just menu items which don't fit the screen.

The menu expands like this if you change the screen size

[image]

and if you change the screen size to smaller size all the items hidden into hamburger menu.

For example on a particular screen size how can I hide search box and some items into hamburger menu? It doesn't even have to add into hamburger menu. how I can hide them entirely.

I have tried this approach

```
@media (min-width: 769px) {
  .nav.navbar-nav > li {
    display: none;
  }
  .nav.navbar-nav > li:nth-child(1),
  .nav.navbar-nav > li:nth-child(2),
  .nav.navbar-nav > li:nth-child(3) {
    display: block;
  }
  .lt-ie9 .nav.navbar-nav > li:first-child,
  .lt-ie9 .nav.nav.navbar-nav > li:first-child + li,
  .lt-ie9 .nav.navbar-nav > li:first-child + li + li {
    display: block;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 790px) {
  .header-navbar .nav-icons,
  .header-navbar .nav.navbar-nav > li.nav-all {
    margin-right: 0px;
  }
  .header-navbar:after {
    display: none;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 899px) {
  .nav.navbar-nav > li:nth-child(4) {
    display: block;
  }
  .lt-ie9 .nav.navbar-nav > li:first-child + li + li + li {
    display: block;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .nav.navbar-nav > li:nth-child(5),
  .nav.navbar-nav > li:nth-child(6),
  .nav.navbar-nav > li:nth-child(7),
  .nav.navbar-nav > li:nth-child(8),
  .nav.navbar-nav > li:nth-child(9),
  .nav.navbar-nav > li:nth-child(10),
  .nav.navbar-nav > li:nth-child(11),
  .nav.navbar-nav > li:nth-child(12),
  .nav.navbar-nav > li:nth-child(13),
  .nav.navbar-nav > li:nth-child(14) {
    display: block;
  }
  .lt-ie9 .nav.navbar-nav > li:first-child + li + li + li {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Comment: you'll need JS for this

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your html follows standard structure for a Bootstrap navbar:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="hideMe">Item</li>
    ...
</ul>

@media (max-width: 1280px) {
    .navbar-nav .hideMe {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have something like this:

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0; margin: 0; list-style: none; font-family: 'Segoe UI';}
a {text-decoration: none;}

nav ul li {display: inline-block;}
nav ul li a {display: block; width: 100px; text-align: center; line-height: 1.5; padding: 5px; border: 1px solid #ccc;}

@media screen and (max-width: 460px) {
  li + li + li + li ~ li {display: none;}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 555px) {
  li + li + li + li + li ~ li {display: none;}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  li + li + li + li + li + li ~ li {display: none;}
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 6</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 7</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 8</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 9</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 10</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Check the example in the emulator view.

Comment: I have tried this one. I edited my question and added the code that I tried. Can you check if it's okay?

Comment: Boss, `.nav.navbar-nav > li:nth-child(4) {
    display: block;
  }` will only `display block` one single `li` right?